# how to use json in java for 10 datas

Tags: java, json

hello
i have an some 10 datas from db with attribute same attribute name

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 json.put("text",value1);
 json.put("title",value2);
 json.put("url",value3);
```

i use this above code i am getting similar to this

```
 {"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"}
 {"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"}
 {"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"}
 {"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"}
```

while i parse it in php i am getting an null value i dont know y .. can you tell me where i am wrong...

Answer (score 2):

your output should be something like this to be parsable

```
 [{"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"},
 {"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"},
 {"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"},
 {"text":"texting is not bad","title":"tesing","url":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/"}]
```

and for this you should be using `JSONArray`.

Comment: ` $str = file_get_contents($url);
$str=trim($str);
var_dump(json_decode($str));` i use this to decode the json in php

Comment: I'm not very familiar with php but you could use http://json.parser.online.fr/ to see if you have valid json.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will have to create a JSON Array to hold your 10 datas, like so:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("text",value1);
    json.put("title",value2);
    json.put("url",value3);
    jsonArray.put(json);
}
```

**Output**, See [Bala R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273200/bala-r)'s response.